# VB.NET WebBrowser disable javascript

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

Is there a way to disable javascript webbrowser in vb.net?

Comment: Do you mean in the WebBrowser control on a forms app, or in the user's web browser on a web app?

Comment: Actually, it is possible, read my answer.

Answer (score 1):

works for me:

```
Private Function TrimScript(ByVal htmlDocText As String) As String


    While htmlDocText.ToLower().IndexOf("<script type=""text/javascript"">") > -1
        Dim s_index As Integer = htmlDocText.ToLower().IndexOf("<script type=""text/javascript"">")
        Dim e_index As Integer = htmlDocText.ToLower().IndexOf("</script>")
        htmlDocText = htmlDocText.Remove(s_index, e_index - s_index)
    End While
    Return htmlDocText

End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString(yourUrl)
    Dim wb As New WebBrowser
    wb.Navigate("")
    Do While wb.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop
    Dim script As String = TrimScript(result)
    wb.DocumentText = script

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work if they've simply used `<script>` or added script as an attribute (e.g. `onload="alert('foo');"`). Script code can be inserted in so many ways that there will always be things that are missed.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: No.

The slightly longer answer is: No, the web-browser control API does not allow disabling standard browser functionality.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443425/c-sharp-stop-webbrowser-control-from-loading-images-flash-script-etc

Comment: the answer is yes, check out my answer, perhaps give it a try if it interests you. if you have any questions, hit me up.

Answer (score 0):

No really...but if you getting that annoying error message that pops up saying a script is running then you can turn the property of the webbrowser's suppress-errors "true"

Comment: Actually, you can, check out my msg.

Answer (score 0):

Which popup message do you want to disable? If it's the alert message, try this, obviously resolving the window or frame object to your particular needs, I’ve just assumed top-level document, but if you need an iframe you can access it using window.frames(0). for the first frame and so on... (re the JavaScript part)... here is some code, assuming WB is your webbrowser control...

WB.Document.parentWindow.execScript "window.alert = function () { };", "JScript"

You must run the above code only after the entire page is done loading, i understand this is very difficult to do (and a full-proof version hasn't been published yet) however I have been doing it (full proof) for some time now, and you can gather hints on how to do this accurately if you read some of my previous answers labelled "webbrowser" and "webbrowser-control", but getting back to the question at hand, if you want to cancel the .confirm JavaScript message, just replace window.alert with window.confirm (of course, qualifying your window. object with the correct object to reach the document hierarchy you are working with). You can also disable the .print method with the above technique and the new IE9 .prompt method as well.

If you want to disable JavaScript entirely, you can use the registry to do this, and you must make the registry change before the webbrowser control loads into memory, and every time you change it (on & off) you must reload the webbrowser control out and into memory (or just restart your application).

The registry key is `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\` - the keyname is `1400` and the value to disable it is 3, and to enable it is 0.

Of course, because there are 5 zones under the Zones key, you need to either change it for the active zone or for all zones to be sure. However, you really don't need to do this if all you want to do si supress js dialog popup messages.

Let me know how you go, and if I can help further.

Comment: What if the page contains some script that is executed before the page has finished loading?