# How can i blocked dialog box for webbrowser c#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, browser, webbrowser-control

How can i blocked dialog box for webbrowser?

on the dialog box. And my program is paused...
How can i  blocked dialog box.
İ can use this code but its not works.

```
        private void webExplorer_NewWindow(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Comment: please try answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164061/ by @Erx_VB.NExT.Coder

Answer (score 1):

It's a javascript `alert()` call.  See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp).