# Increasing the security when using WebBrowser

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, azure, webbrowser-control

I've looked through several similar questions on SO but haven't found something quite like what I need, so my question is this:

I want to take a screenshot (thumbnail) of a URL after the user provides one. I was going to use Awesomium because they provide a fairly simple solution for screengrabs.  Unfortunately, Awesomium won't compile in an x64 application, and since I'm building this with ASP.NET for Windows Azure, I can't switch to x86.

So I'm left with a less-elegant solution, using Windows.Forms WebBrowser to load the url and take the screenshot (as shown here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95439/Get-ASP-NET-C-2-0-Website-Thumbnail-Screenshot ).

Ugly, I know, but it works with most pages (there is the occasional white screenshot), but now I'm concerned with security.

If the user inputs a malicious URL and the WebBrowser loads it, what is to stop it from running harmful code and downloading a virus to the server where the app is hosted?

There are several services and websites that offer similar functionality, albeit with different approaches, but the core idea is the same: the site must open up the URL and render the page in order to grab the screenshot. So what kind of measures would one expect them to take to thwart viruses and malicious URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest threat to your application would be client script executing in your browser control (i.e. JavaScript and client-side VBScript). It appears it is not possible to disable JavaScript programmatically in the `WebBrowser` object:

- [VB.NET WebBrowser disable javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4164061/413180)
- [Disable javascript in
  WinForms WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10623697/413180)

Stripping `<script>` tags in the first question's [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13185408/413180) is not the way to go for security, as there are so many other ways script can get inserted.

Changing `window.alert` in the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12213694/413180) won't work as it needs the page to load fully first, and it is possible for script to execute before then. Also, this would only stop the `alert` function and not prevent script code in any other way.

Changing the registry settings as suggested in this answer may be the way to go, but this appears to be the same as changing Internet Explorer settings to high security for the internet zone (or selecting custom and disabling Active Scripting). If you are always in control of the machine where your app is loaded from, then manually disabling scripting in Internet Explorer options could be a viable solution.

Most client-side internet threats such as drive-by downloads involve script in some way, so this approach will go a long way in protecting your app.

However, there are other exploits such as the [Windows Metafile vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Metafile_vulnerability) that can harm a client machine.

> Viewing a website in a web browser that automatically opens WMF files, in which case any potential malicious code may be automatically downloaded and opened. Internet Explorer, the default Web browser for all versions of Microsoft Windows since 1996, does this.

However, making sure your machines are patched with the latest Windows Updates will secure you against threats like these. This will leave [zero-day attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-day_attack) against Internet Explorer or the `WebBrowser` object, which you will not be able to do much about. I would suggest running your app on an isolated machine (or VM) which would then upload the screenshot to another server (e.g. via the web) which would help mitigate threats in this scenario.

Comment: "Running your app on an isolated machine (or VM) which would then upload the screenshot to another server (e.g. via the web)" - this is a fantastic suggestion.  After reading your comment, it seems it may be worth just paying for a website screenshot API to avoid these vulnerabilities - Zero-Day attacks will always be an issue.