# Disable javascript in WinForms WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, webbrowser-control

How could I disable javascript entirely on WebBrowser in WinForms?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET WebBrowser disable javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164061/vb-net-webbrowser-disable-javascript)

Comment: The WebBrowser control is part of the .net framework so this is a duplicate.

Comment: You can but is pain. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443425/c-sharp-stop-webbrowser-control-from-loading-images-flash-script-etc).

Comment: I'm sure you must have a temptation to simply write code to eliminate all _<script>...</script>_ and tada. That wouldn't work. You could use <script type = "text/javascript"> and the script would not be blocked. And even if you managed to block all scripts that way, there would still exist the sneaky _<body onload = "JS">_ thingy. Also, it is kind of obvious that the webbrowser makers (who probably also made IE) were too lame to add a disableJS function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Client apps cannot disable JavaScript in the browser.

Comment: do I have any alternatives in order to prevent pages from opening pop-ups?

Comment: If you're writing the code, wouldn't you have control over this?

Comment: I'm writing the winform, not the pages it's webbrowser visit.

Comment: Incorrect. You can control the features of the Web Browser control using an IInternetSecurityManager and/or the ambient flags.

Answer (score 0):

With this you can disable warning from javascript

```
webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

Comment: that just disables warnings, the code itself is still executed.