# WebBrowser control - enter and keep offline mode

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control, offline-browsing

I would like to manually load HTML into a web browser control and make sure it does not create any internet traffic, so just show the content to the best of its abilities.

As specified in MSDN, [WebBrowser.IsOffline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.isoffline(v=vs.110).aspx) is read-only.

Is there a way to set it (without using reflection hacks)?

Or do I have to resort to using a 3rd party control for this:

- [The most complete C# Webbrowser wrapper control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18935/The-most-complete-C-Webbrowser-wrapper-control)

Comment: If you do go with a third party control, dont use the one you linked, try this - http://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/

Comment: @EkoostikMartin: Thanks for the link, I especially like this part: **100% managed C# code**, the one I found is written in C++ and thus requires a `regsvr`. Not a deal breaker, but being biased towards managed code, I will consider using it if no other options are posted. You can post it as an answer - I will definitely upvote it.

Comment: Do you want to use IE cache?

Comment: @Joiner: No, I will be supplying the HTML manually.

Comment: @Joiner: I was looking for a way to safely display the web page, without it going to the internet and downloading more stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [`WebBrowser.AllowNavigation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.allownavigation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `False`.

> Whether the control can navigate to another page after its initial page has been loaded.

Comment: I keep getting errors similar to this one: http://snag.gy/fewZq.jpg, ScriptErrorsSuppressed seems to help, but I'm still not sure if it's doing any external requests in order to load. For example, if there is a Java call, such as a redirect to another page, would it fire?

Comment: Can I virtually cut the wire for the web browser control? It should always appear as offline, even if network is available for the rest of application.

Comment: Interesting, but would probably not prevent ajax callbacks, i.e. dynamic HTML. I'll check it out later in the day though. +1 but leaving unaccepted in case anyone else has other ideas. Don't worry though, if nobody else provides input within 24 hours, I will accept it then.

Comment: Setting `DocumentText` together with `AllowNavigation = False` seems to very close, i.e. a redirect is successfully blocked `WebBrowser1.DocumentText = "<BODY onLoad='window.location = ""http://www.page-2.com"";'>"`. I would, however, prefer to disable JS popups if there are any, so the user can just see content. Stuff like this: `WebBrowser1.DocumentText = "<BODY onLoad=""alert('hello world!')"">"` Unfortunately, [there is no way to disable JS in a client application](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10623739/897326). I will probably use a 3rd party HTML renderer then. Accepting your answer...