# Visual Studio C# Win-Forms Application webbrowser loading very slow

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem with my webbrowser in my C# Win-Forms Application
I have downloaded 250 wikipedia pages and have edited the .html code so the local page looks nice.
The problem is that it takes the webbrowser about 5 seconds to load everything.
If I turn off the internet on the pc it loads the webbrowser instantly and everything looks fine. This problem appears with all the 250 pages.

Now my question is if i can restrict the internet connection for the application or what else i could do to make it load faster.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488569/webbrowser-control-enter-and-keep-offline-mode

Answer (score 0):

All resources you dont get of the internet, but from local storage  are loaded faster,

if it is an option to include these files in the application that is what i would recommend.

if not, you could strip all the pages of all images to gain loading speed.

Comment: I currently have the files in the application /Debug folder but not really "in" the application itself
What is the best way to move it into the application resources?